# Grid onscroll event needed

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm using extjs 4.2. I have a grid with around 20 columns, and ofcourse it has a horizontal scroll bar. What I need is the event on the gridwhich captures the horizontal scroll

The scroll bar is a part of the grid, not the window.

Any suggestions appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did you try  : https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?107653-Handling-Ext.Panel-scroll-events ?

Comment: Maybe you can find your anwser here


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116913/extjs4-catching-the-scroll-event-on-panel

Comment: @BenoitCuvelier yes tried it after you posted it. But it doesn't work.

Comment: @MichaelLane The grid doesnt render to any div/html holder. so i cant use that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bodyscroll` event of the view. Here is [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/uua)

Comment: Any way to do it without using renderTo?

Comment: Actually you don't need to use renderTo at all, it is just for test. In fiddle I have no parent view, so I should render my object to the body element. Normally you have some primary viewport, that manages all screens and a grid will be part of it.

Comment: You're right. We tweaked the code a bit in the 'afterrender' event and it worked. Thanks alot!
This is what we have right now :
 thisGrid.view.getEl().on('scroll', function(e, t) {
//onscroll event code 
});